# JS artificial delay between async requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am trying to find a way to introduce some delay between requests. Basically I have an async method called likePhotos that iterates an array of photos and calls likePhoto() for each. Rather than fire off all those at the same time I would like to have a second delay between each call to likePhoto and then finally return to the caller once they are all complete.

```
async likePhotos(photos) {
  // Run the function over all photos
  var likes = photos.map(function(p, index, photos){
     this.likePhoto(p);
  }, this);

  return Promise.all(likes);
}

likePhoto(p) {
  let { token } = this.state;

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    Http
    .post('/api/photos/' + p.id + '/likes', {}, { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log("YEAH");
      resolve();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("Failed to like photo: " + p.id);
      reject(error.message);
    })
  });
}
```

setTimeout doesn't quite seem to fit the bill here. I'm a JS noob so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you're wanting to throttle requests to likePhoto I wonder if it's worth implementing the throttling there to avoid the need to handle it here. Either using a queue and `setInterval` or `setTimeout` might simplify things for you. You could also offer an argument/option to skip the queue if desired. Where you implement the throttling really depends on your requirements as I realise my comment here may contradict the approach taken on guest271314's answer below.

Comment: my previous comment was referring to a comment on the answer not the answer itself - sorry my comments have been a bit of a mess on this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimneout()` within `likePhoto`; `return` `this.likePhoto()` with `index` passed to multiply `1000` by current index from within `.map()` at `likePhotos()` call

```
async likePhotos(photos) {
  // Run the function over all photos
  var likes = photos.map(function(p, index, photos) {
     // return from `.map()` callback
     return this.likePhoto(p, index);
  }, this);

  return Promise.all(likes);
}

likePhoto(p, index) {
  let { token } = this.state;

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    Http
    .post('/api/photos/' + p.id + '/likes', {}, { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log("YEAH");
      setTimeout(function() {
        resolve();
      }, 1000 * index);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("Failed to like photo: " + p.id);
      reject(error.message);
    })
  });
}
```

Comment: will need index as multiplier for duration though if they all need to be a second apart ... or they will all run at same time a second after loop runs

Comment: @charlietfl Good point. Also noticed `this.likePhoto()` is not returned from `.map()`

Comment: Could also possibly wrap the call to `likePhoto` in a promise which might avoid the addition of an argument to `likePhoto` although my solution mightn't be as readable

Comment: @Brian Do you mean wrap `likePhoto` in another `Promise`?

Comment: I meant something like `return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){ setTimeout(function(){ this.likePhoto(p).then(resolve, reject) }, 1000 * index)  })` that the throttling is handled within the likePhotos call which might be best if you're only wanting throttling for `likePhotos` not all calls to `likePhoto`

Comment: So yeah essentially just wrapping likePhoto in another promise :) sorry haven't had my coffee yet.

Comment: @Brian Was attempting to not create another `Promise`, if possible, unless necessary to meet requirement.

Comment: Worth noting that there's a scoping issue in the example in my comment - setTimeout and this (as setTimeout will change execution context making the `this` that we want out of scope)

Comment: @Brian `this` is not used inside of `setTimeout`

Comment: Sorry I was commenting on a mistake in the code in my comment - I've edited to clarify

Answer (score 0):

Add a counter for simultaneous Http requests. Most browsers can send 6 simultaneous requests. After sending six requests wait for response from all six requests. Once response from all six requests received, send another six requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the call to `likePhotos` in a promise then resolve it within a setTimeout. I've captured a reference to `this` as the `setTimeout` call will change context.

I've wrapped the changes in a mock object so that I could test it out but the concept is the same :)

```
function Test(){
    var self = this;
    this.likePhoto = function(a){
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
           console.log(a)
           resolve(a);
        });

    };
    this.likePhotos = function(photos){
        var likes = photos.map(function(p, index, photos){
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    self.likePhoto(p).then(resolve, reject)
                }, 1000 * index)
            })
        }, this);

        return Promise.all(likes);

    }

}
var a = new Test();

a.likePhotos([1,2,3]).then(console.log);
```